How to prevent someone from copying POST request from developer tools and modifying request payload?
We are using http-only cookie based JWT authentication in our MERN application.
Recently we experienced a suspicious activity from a user. User created an account and then made a POST request with a payload value which can be only set by the code. But when we check the logs, the value received on the Express.js server was not looking like its being sent via the code. It looked like the POST request body was altered. Our guess is that the user copied the POST request from the Network tab, pasted the copied content in the console tab, changed the body content and made the request to the server from the console tab. Since this was on the same browser page, our Express.js allowed this as CORS was configured to allow this domain.
After this incident, we implemented some checks on the server for the request body. But there are other areas of application where this incident can happen.
How can we ensure that if someone tries to copy the POST request and alter the payload, we need to check on the server that this request ws originated from the developer tools console tab and not from the application? Or if there is a way to handle this situation?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Some of the quickest fix that comes to mind would be to Validate all input on the server side, you can use the Helmet.js package, Implement CSRF tokens.
